# Maven configuration for specific goal only

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-javadoc-plugin

I discovered that the `maven-javadoc-plugin` doesn't produce a jar when running the `jar` goal with a `destDir` configured (probably a bug). I need a `destDir` for my `javadoc` goal.

So, I'd like to specify a `destDir` config **only** when the `javadoc` goal is being executed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: since you are probably executing this in a ci environment, just use `-DdestDir=<destDir>` as additional parameter, or is this no option?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's wrong with using [`-DdestDir`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html#outputDirectory) in the `maven-javadoc-plugin:jar` goal?

Comment: Why do you need to change the `destDir` ?

Comment: @AlexN javadoc:jar is actually being called by the release plugin, not by me directly, and it would be a pain to supply a -DdestDir each time I cut a release. Specifying it in the <configuration> *should* work. Right?

Comment: Show us the relevant part of the command you are executing to run the release.

Comment: @AlexN mvn:release-perform. Either way, mvn javadoc:jar fails to generate a jar when `destDir` is configured in the POM.

Comment: JavaDoc is not called by maven-release-plugin...it might be part of a release profile...which is executed during running of the release plugin...